# Changing .NET access from internal to public isn't invalidating assembly cache?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, gac

We exposed a method in a DLL in a web app, changing it from:

```
internal void Foo() { ... }
```

to:

```
public void Foo() { ... }
```

so another assembly could call it, and then deployed the web app.  It works ok locally, but the servers are getting access permission issues as if they were still using the `internal` version.  It seems very persistent (ie we cleaned, redeployed, etc).

Is it possible the .NET assembly cache or some similar mechanism is not sensitive to changes to access modifier and isn't invalidating properly, so we have stale versions of the DLL hiding somewhere?

Comment: Did you change the `Guid` and `AssemblyVersion` attributes in the project's AssemblyInfo.cs after updating the interface?

Comment: No - and (hiding my shame) we never have, AssemblyVersion has been set to `1.0.0.0` for going on 10 years now.

Comment: I'd update those two attributes and see if that fixes it.  I think it might be getting confused.  Its probably ok if you add to the interface, but if you change an existing function it could cause a problem.

Comment: I expect it will fix it -- I was hoping for a definitive answer like, yes, "access modifiers are not part of the assembly cache's hash" or something like that.

Comment: If the assemblies are in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) that may be the issue if you've placed the new ones somewhere else.